# how to vue-json-to-csv with vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Good afternoon everyone I'm having a problem converting json to csv, I'm using a lib I found at https://github.com/angeliquekom/vue-json-to-csv, to be very interesting, but I'm having trouble passing an arrau for component.

my code:

```
<template>
            <vue-json-to-csv :json-data="data"
          :labels="{
            id: { title: 'id' },
            co_tipo_nota: { title: 'co_tipo_nota' },
            ds_nota: { title: 'ds_nota' },
            ds_outro_criterio: { title: 'ds_outro_criterio' },
            ds_nofl_avaliacao_anonimata: { title: 'fl_avaliacao_anonima' },
            dt_nota: { title: 'dt_nota' },

          }"
          @success="val => handleSuccess(val)"
          @error="val => handleError(val)">
          <button>
            <b>My custom button</b>
          </button>
        </vue-json-to-csv>
        </template>

        <script>
        import VueJsonToCsv from 'vue-json-to-csv'
        import { baseApiUrl } from '@/global'
        import axios from 'axios'

        export default {
             name: 'DowloadCvsThree',
             components: {
                VueJsonToCsv,
            },

            data: function() {
                return {
                    mode: 'save',
                    nota: {},
                    notas: [],

                }
            },
            props: {
                notas: Array
            },
             methods: {
                loadUsers() {
                    const url = `${baseApiUrl}/notas`
                    axios.get(url).then(res => {
                        this.notas = res.data
                    })
                },
            mounted() {
                this.loadUsers()
            }

         }
        }
        </script>

        <style>

        </style>



    the error return is ?
    [o erro][1]
    [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/llHeZ.png
```

can anybody help me? I'm trying to pass an array to the json-to-csv: json-data = "data" component, but the date is not an array with I do? 
he address of lib npm is: https://github.com/angeliquekom/vue-json-to-csv

awaiting return?